# Выпадающее javascript (JQuery) меню

Tags: jquery, меню, javascript

Всем привет. Облазил весь интернет в поисках подобной кнопки, которую я сейчас опишу.
Есть элементы

```
 <div id="wrap">
...

    <div id="button_menu" onlick="Menu.Show();">Кнопка, которая вытаскивает меню</div>
    <div id="box_menu">... различная навигация ...</div>
...
</div>
```

Вопрос в чем, мне нужно сделать так:
При нажатие на кнопку выпадает меню. Если кликать внутри навигации, то меню остается на месте, а клик вне меню сворачивает меню. В идеале было бы так же вытаскивать меню с помощью щелчка, а если курсор на кнопке или на самой навигации, то меню не подвижно, если курсор выходит за пределы, то через 5 секунд закрывается меню, если в течение 5 секунд курсор оказался в меню, то он остается открытым.

Технически описать получилось. А вот на практике знаний маловато. Максимум, что написал я - это открытие меню по клику и повторный клик в любое место, в том числе и в меню, закрывает окно. Но это плохой вариант, тем более, для каждой менюшки нужно прописывать событие по клику в документе.

Есть ли наметки, готовые и т.д. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Nick, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не в полном объеме по вашим требованиям, но вот сделал [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/deEG8/)

Comment: Прекрасно! Спасибо большое, Deonis!